# Grid with rows that have different number of columns

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to programmatically create a Grid that has 3 rows and 2 columns, but the last row only has 1 column instead of 2?

```
public class MyGrid : Grid
{
    public void DefineRowsAndColumns()
    {
        // I know you can add RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions here, but how to make them uneven?
    }
}
```

I'm not trying to get someone to do my homework here...I just want to know how I can get a grid to have rows with different number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the ColumnSpan property to make content span multiple columns

```
var label = new Label { Text = "Row 1" };
myGrid.Children.Add(label,0,0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(label,2);
```

the Label will span 2 columns, effectively making that row contain only a single column